# How to apply a query on 2 databases (having no foreign keys) in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-key-relationship, cx-oracle

File `myapp/models.py` has this sample code..

```
from django.db import models

# model for 'user' table in database oracle_dbuser1:user 
class User(models.Model):
    . . .
    customerid = models.BigIntegerField()

# model for 'customer' table in database oracle_dbuser2:customer
# Note that there is no Foreign key integrity among these legacy tables.
class Customer(models.Model):
    . . .
    customerid = models.BigIntegerField()
```

and the file `myapp/admin.py` has the following code:

```
from maasusers.models import User, Customer
from django.contrib import admin

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # A handy constant for the name of the alternate database.
    db_one = 'dbuser1'
    db_two = 'dbuser2'

    # display in a list
    list_display = (. . .) # question 1

    def queryset(self, request):
        result = super(UserAdmin, self).queryset(request).using(self.db_one) # question 2
        return result

# Register the Poll class
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
admin.site.register(Customer, UserAdmin)
```

Question 1: Refer above: I want to display columns of both the tables. How can I achieve this? Eg. `Select usr.col1, usr.col2, cust.col1, cust.col10 from user usr, customer cust where usr.col2 = cust.col3;`

Question 2: How to write a corresponding `queryset()` function using the `using` function?

Answer (score 3):

[Database Routers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers) can help you avoid the need to use `using()` on a queryset. You inform django which databases to use for which models. I suggest you read the documentation around routers thoroughly, as they can be a pain (we use them at our work).

Note the following though:

> This example won't work if any of the models in myapp contain relationships to models outside of the other database. Cross-database relationships introduce referential integrity problems that Django can't currently handle.

Django doesn't handle cross database joins, whether you want to use keys to join or not. If you need data from both models, you can execute two separate queries, and do the join yourself in code. I don't know how this would apply to the Admin though.

An alternative would be to create a view, joining the cross database tables within the database itself. However, you won't be able to save instances back.

Hopefully this is a good starting point for your investigations.

Comment: Thanks for the info and clarification Josh! Hmm.. interesting problem though.. :(

Comment: @Aditya369 perhaps you shouldn't mark this answer as correct right yet. You'll discourage other people from coming by with possibly an answer that solves your problem, since I've really just told you why it doesn't work.